# i get error in my react js console log >> xhr.js:187 POST http://localhost:3000/api/users/login 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

1. when I axios.post('/api/users/login') it fails
2. i get error in my react js console log >> xhr.js:187 POST http://localhost:3000/api/users/login 401 (Unauthorized)
3. even though I think the code in loginScreen.js is correct, what's wrong?, please help me

this is my loginScreen.js file

```
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/rules-of-hooks */
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Form, Button, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import MainScreen from '../../components/mainScreen'

function loginScreen() {
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState(false)

  const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
        },
      }

      setLoading(true)

      const { data } = await axios.post(
        '/api/users/login',
        {
          email,
          password,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
          },
        }
      )

      console.log(data)
      // localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data))
      setLoading(false)
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.response.data.message)
    }
  }

  return (
    <MainScreen title='LOGIN'>
      <div className='loginContainer'>
        <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          <Form.Group controlId='formBasicEmail'>
            <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type='email'
              value={email}
              placeholder='Enter email'
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group controlId='formBasicPassword'>
            <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type='password'
              value={password}
              placeholder='Password'
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Form.Group>

          <Button variant='primary' type='submit'>
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form>
        <Row className='py-3'>
          <Col>
            New Customer ? <Link to='/register'>Register Here</Link>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </MainScreen>
  )
}

export default loginScreen
```

and this is my router in backend

```
const express = require('express')
const { registerUser, authUser } = require('../controllers/userController')

const router = express.Router()

router.route('/').post(registerUser)
router.route('/login').post(authUser)

module.exports = router
```

this is my authUser

```
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler')
const User = require('../models/userModel')
const generateToken = require('../utils/generateToken')

const registerUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password, pic } = req.body
  const userExists = await User.findOne({ email })

  if (userExists) {
    res.status(404)
    throw new Error('User already exists')
  }

  const user = await User.create({
    name,
    email,
    password,
    pic,
  })

  if (user) {
    res.status(201).json({
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      pic: user.pic,
      token: generateToken(user._id),
    })
  } else {
    res.status(400)
    throw new Error('User not found')
  }
})

const authUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body
  const user = await User.findOne({ email })

  if (user && (await user.matchPassword(password))) {
    res.json({
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      pic: user.pic,
      token: generateToken(user._id),
    })
  } else {
    res.status(401)
    throw new Error('Invalid Email or Password')
  }
})

module.exports = { registerUser, authUser }
```

thank's a lot ..

Comment: Your server is running on PORT 3000? And your front end? Also, did you try your **/api/users/login** API through POSTMAN?